# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in a simple C code

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, coredump

I am new in C. I am referring to the book "The C Programming Language" by Brian W Kernighian and Dennis Ritchie. 
There is a code for pointer increment and assignment given in the book as follows.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
    {
        char *s = "Goal";
        char *t = "Home";
        while(*s++ = *t++) printf(*s);
        return 0;
    }
```

The code is saved and compiled using the command

```
gcc ptr.c -o ptr -std=c99
```

Now on running the code by running command

```
./ptr
```

I get the following error

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

The error seems to be inside the `while` loop condition.
But the code is exactly as given in the book.
What am I missing?

Comment: Note that `while(*s++ = *t++)` is absolutely horrible style.

Comment: @starblue It's not. As K&R noted it: “Although this may seem cryptic at first sight, the notational convenience is considerable, and the idiom should be mastered, because you will see it frequently in C programs.“

Comment: @JSmyth Have you considered that K&R might be wrong?

Comment: @starblue i.e. wrong commenting on the style of the language they introduced by their very own selves? If what you wanted to say was that there's a better, widely adopted way of doing the same - please share here.

Comment: You should avoid putting assignments in the middle of expressions, as that quickly becomes unreadable or even results in unspecified behavior. Here we have three assignments, including `=`, which can easily be confused with `==`, which will generate a warning if sensible compiler options are used.

Comment: @starblue what would those sensible compiler options be? Just wanna try myself if I get a warning. I will use GCC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`s` and `t` are both string literals, and you can't modify a string literal. But this piece of code

```
*s++ = *t++
```

will modify `s`, which causes segmentation fault.

To fix it, use a `char` array. I also modified the `printf` part to make it legal.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char arr[] = "Goal";
    char *s = arr;
    char *t = "Home";
    while(*s++ = *t++) 
        ;
    printf("%s\n", arr);
    return 0;
}
```

However, I think this program is better done using an individual function to copy the string, the program will look clearer.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void my_strcpy(char *s, char *t);

int main()
{
    char s[] = "Goal";
    char *t = "Home";
    my_strcpy(s, t);
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}

void my_strcpy(char *s, char *t)
{
    while(*s++ = *t++) 
        ;
}
```

Comment: ummm, if you do that then `s++` won't compile

Comment: After changing `char *s = "Goal";` to `char s[] = "Goal";`, the program would not compile. I get the following error on compilation. `ptr3.c: In function ‘main’:
ptr3.c:7:10: error: lvalue required as increment operand
`

Comment: @ajb Fixed. I guess the original program in the book is supposed to pass `s` as a function argument though. In that way, it will decay to a pointer.

Comment: still not fixed, it's still going to try to read at a bad address

Comment: This code seems to fix all the problems. But I do need to understand what error was I making. Can you explain?

Comment: @user2801303 The error is that you try to modify a string literal. I added a second program, that should be a better version. Remember that when array names are passed as function argument, they decay to a pointer.

Comment: If you copied the program straight out of the book, then the error was either (1) you typed something wrong, or (2) you copied a program that the authors were giving you as an example of what **not** to do.  Unfortunately, I don't have the book so I can't really give you an answer.

Comment: The my_strcpy function as mentioned by @YuHao was exactly what was given in the book.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `printf` expects the first parameter to be a `char *`, that is, something that points to a character, or the address of a character.  When you say `printf(*s)` you're passing it an actual character, i.e. a number from 0 to 255 or -128 to 127, and the program is going to treat that number as an address, which isn't going to be a valid address on your system.

Comment: Even when I change the printf statement to something trivial like `printf("hello");` inside the loop, I get the same error. This implies that the problem is not within the printf statement.

Comment: @user2801303 There were two problems.  One was inside the `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

When ever we say *s = "hello" , s is pointing to an address which is present in text segment("hello" goes into text segment). So obviously changing the value of text segment results in SEGV termination.

And for s[] = "hello" if we do *s++, we are incrementing (modifying) the base address so we got "lvalue required as increment operand" error.